# How does _init_ file in Flask project work when starting the server?

Tags: python, flask

I'm reading the [Flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/factory/) and learned that in large application structure the code is moved from single `app.py` file to 'application factory function' `create_app` in `_init_.py` file, then the server can be started like this:

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

I wonder how does the last command work behind the scene, because there's no explicit call to this factory function anywhere in the code hence no app returned?

Another [Flask doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/packages/) tries to explain why such project structure is used but in that case code in `_init_.py` creates `app` explicitly:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import yourapplication.views
```

[python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) says:

> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later (deeper) on the module search
>   path. In the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but
>   it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the
>   **all** variable, described later.

The last sentence mentions about 'initialization code' which can be applied in the second case(and simple project structure with `app.py` file) but I failed to apply it to the first case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [flask source code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/cli.py#L71), they check if a function called `create_app` exists.

```
# Search for app factory functions.
for attr_name in ('create_app', 'make_app'):
    app_factory = getattr(module, attr_name, None)

    if inspect.isfunction(app_factory):
        try:
            app = call_factory(script_info, app_factory)

            if isinstance(app, Flask):
                return
```

It evens says so in the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appfactories/#using-applications):

> Flask will automatically detect the factory (create_app or make_app) in myapp.